# cannot connect to postgrespql on localhost from tomcat application: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Permission denied (connect failed)

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, database-connection

I cannot make a connection from a tomcat application to the postresql server on localhost:5432. The log tells me this:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

However, I verified the sql-server is running using a command line client jisql and a jdbc-jar downloaded from postgreql.

```
java -cp jisql/lib/jisql.jar:jisql/lib/jopt-simple-3.2.jar:jisql/postgresql-42.2.12.jar com.xigole.util.sql.Jisql -user uuuuuu -password ppppp -driver postgresql -cstring jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dddddd -c \;
```

which is working, but the same config as in my java app (using grails and hibernate):

```
dataSource {
  dbCreate = "create"
  url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dddddd"
  username = "uuuuuu"
  password = "pppppp"
}
```

gives me:

```
2020-05-23 07:58:17,413 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:52)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:216)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Permission denied (connect failed)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144)
    ... 11 more
```

I am confused by the *ConnectException: Permission denied* message. whe I really try to connect to a different port like the first error message suggests I get the familliar *java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)*

I also tried to pass *-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"* to tomcat with no avail

software used:

- CentOS 7
- postgresql 9.2.24
- tomcat 7.0.76
- openjdk version "1.8.0_252"

Comment: The permission denied error would suggest that your operating system disallows you to create a socket connection.

Comment: thx for the suggestion, so i logged in as the tomcat user and tried to connect usig the command line sql client but had the same result: no problem connection to the database. so the user has permission to create a socket connection.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with *CentOS 7*, *PostgreSQL 9.6.23*, *Tomcat 7.0.76*. *OpenJDK 1.8.0_302*.

There is few steps to solve it :

1. Change references to "ident" and "md5" to "trust" in the pg_hba.conf file.

I was able to identify the location of this file in my system by the following command:

```
psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW hba_file'.
```

2. Set two SELinux boolean values to on(which were off).

The boolean values to set are "httpd_can_network_connect" and "tomcat_can_network_connect_db". You can check the values of each with the following commands:

```
    getsebool -a | grep "httpd_can_network_connect "
    
    getsebool -a | grep "tomcat_can_network_connect_db "
```

Both values were "off" on my system.

I changed them both to "on" with the following commands:

```
    sudo setsebool -P tomcat_can_network_connect_db on
    
    sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

3. Restart PostgreSQL, and now it's fixed !